# set MaxRecords with Java Jacob library

Tags: java, jacob, windows-search

I'm trying to make use of Windows Search by using [java Jacob library.](http://danadler.com/jacob/) but I'm having troubles to specify the [`maxRecords`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) option to limit the number of rows get back.

I'm trying to do it by using this line:

```
Dispatch.put(connection, "MaxRecords", new Variant(10));
```

After setting up the connection:

```
connection = new Dispatch("ADODB.Connection");
Dispatch.call(connection, "Open", "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");

//-------> error in the following line  <-------
Dispatch.put(connection, "MaxRecords", new Variant(10));

results = Dispatch.call(connection, "Execute",
        "SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified " +
        "FROM SystemIndex " +
        "WHERE Directory='file:C:/my/folder/path' AND Contains('a')").toDispatch();

while (!Dispatch.get(results, "EOF").getBoolean()) {
        Dispatch fields = Dispatch.get(results, "Fields").toDispatch();
        String filename = Dispatch.get(Dispatch.call(fields, "Item", new Integer(0)).toDispatch(), "Value").toString();
        String filedate = Dispatch.get(Dispatch.call(fields, "Item", new Integer(1)).toDispatch(), "Value").toString();
        list.put(filename, filedate);
        Dispatch.call(results, "MoveNext");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
There's no error on compilation but on executing I get this message:

> com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered: 
> At Invoke of: MaxRecords 
> Description: 80020007 / No named arguments. 
> ... 
> Internal Server Error (500) - The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

And this one when accessing through my restful by URL:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request
> You can get technical details [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1).
> Please continue your visit at our home page.

Everything works fine without that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs, the [Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object does not have a `MaxRecords` property.  I think you'd want to set MaxRecords on a [RecordSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object.

EDIT:

I haven't tried these, but would try along the following lines:

```
connection = new Dispatch("ADODB.Connection");
Dispatch.call(connection, "Open", "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';");

String sql = "SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified " +
    "FROM SystemIndex " +
    "WHERE Directory='file:C:/my/folder/path' AND Contains('a')"

recordSet = new Dispatch("ADODB.Recordset");
Dispatch.put(recordSet, "MaxRecords", new Variant(10));

Dispatch.call(recordSet, "Open", sql, connection);

while (!Dispatch.get(recordSet, "EOF").getBoolean()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, so how could I do it?

Comment: I've created the `Dispatch recordSet;` and then adding the two lines you suggested ([like this](http://pastebin.com/kUh1ith5)) but It doesn't seem to work. Getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't pass in null Dispatch object`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access pastebin (corporate proxy), I'll have a look from home later.

Comment: Sorry, [here the initialization](http://pastebin.com/G8wXabS6) of the variables as well.

Comment: which one can you access so that I can share code with you.

Comment: You are still using results in your while loop when you should be using recordSet.